# when to use a behavior and when to use a trigger&action in wpf?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I researcher mvvm in wpf.
I know how to use a behavior and how to use  a trigger&action, but I don't understand when!
I look for info but I find only theoretical metirial, not practical.

thank you!

Comment: It's theoretical question :)

Comment: you are right.... but I want to know in which case use the behavior and in which case to use the action&trigger.

Comment: Behavior encompasses lot many things. You can maintain anything which you think describe an object's behavior in a WPF Behavior. It is upto you to decide that. So, a behavior contain Trigger(s), and an action is fired in response to a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF Behavior is a way to encapsulate a part of complicated UI logic into reusable coded component.

1. http://www.wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html.
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726531(v=expression.40).aspx

   It is a bad practice when a viewmodel and a behavior are strongly-coupled with each other, this can cause a  reusing problem. I think that this is a main different between these two concepts (Triggers&Action/Behavior). Trigger&Action is local solution to convert the Event to command and move the event handling logic toward the viewmodel (you can see here that wthe trigger&action approach is strongly coupled with the viewmodel).

Summary:

1. If you want to create piece of complicated logic, that will be a reusable concept used in more then one control, and moreovere this component won't have any access to the view model - use the behavior approach.
2. If you want just to convert some event to command and to move the event handling logis to viewmodel - use the trigger&action approach.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of objects in WPF which doesn't have any triggers of actions fit to them.
for example: Rectangles.

If you want, for example, to make it possible for clicking on a rectangle and do something, use behavior.

For more information you can look [here](http://www.jayway.com/2013/03/20/behaviors-in-wpf-introduction/) and also [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF)